# Not sure of derivative in derivation of Euler-Lagrange equation: is it some kind of chain rule?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, euler-lagrange-equation

I am reading a derivation on the Euler-Lagrange equations and I don't see how a certain expression arises. In the following I don't see precisely how the derivative in $t$ becomes a summation of partial derivatives in $u$ and $p$:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}J[u + tv] & = \int_a^b \frac{d}{dt}L(x, u+tv, u' + tv')dx \\
& = \int_a^b \bigg[v \frac{\partial}{\partial u}L(x, u+tv, u' + tv') + v' \frac{\partial}{\partial p}L(x, u+tv, u' + tv')] dx,
\end{align}
$$
where $p$ represents $u'$. What is the formula being used here, is it some version of the chain rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's exactly the chain rule.  In general if $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ are differentiable, then
$$
\frac{d}{dt} f(g(t)) = \nabla f(g(t)) \cdot g'(t).
$$
This is what's being used here with $n=3$,
$$
\nabla L = (\partial_x L, \partial_u L, \partial_p L),
$$
and 
$$
g'(t) = (0,v,\partial_x v).
$$

Comment: Why is it that we can say $$
\nabla L = (\partial_x L, \partial_u L, \partial_p L),
$$
when the parameters of $L$ are $x$, $u + tv$, and $u' + tv'$? Should we not be taking partial derivatives with respect to those parameters?

Comment: $L$ is a function of $3$ real variables.  I you prefer you can then write the gradient as $\nabla L = (\partial_1 L, \partial_2 L, \partial_3 L)$, where $\partial_i$ is the derivative with respect to the $i^{th}$ variable.  I wrote it as I did to be consistent with the notation you had used.